# move cursor after final Line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Once in a time I remember that in VSCode I could move my cursor after the final line. That is, if a file doesn't end with a trailing newline and I click the space after the last line, the cursor would be placed after the final line where there is no line number at the left. However, now in VSCode 1.37.1 it not longer behave like this. When I click the space, it just put the cursor at the end of the last line. How can I restore the old behaviour? I searched the settings but I can't find relevant option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 "editor.renderFinalNewline": false
```

I think that is what you want - if there is a newline at the end of the final line you can click in the line below (which has no line number) and enter text there.

[image: demo of finalNewLine setting]